# Timed out when requesting front-end using OkHttp, directly request same back-end interface does not

Tags: http, networking, postman, okhttp

On my project, i have using OkHttp to request another API.

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public HttpResponseWrapper callAndReturnDetail(HttpParam httpParam) {
    Request request = RequestBuilder.build(httpParam);
    try (Response response = okClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return new HttpResponseWrapper(response);
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e){
        //  throw
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //  throw
    }
}
```

But recently,I found a strange problem. I will reproduce this question:

Front-end request URL is :

> GET  http://127.0.0.1:8000/dev/wf/node

It will mapping to real back-end server port:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/wf/node

​   This problem is when I use OkHttp to request **front-end URL**, it will timeout. At the beginning, I think the problem lies in building the backend code for OkHttp requests. But I could not found any problem,  so I try to use PostMan to request this **front-end URL**, its success!

​   I try to use OkHttp to request **back-end URL**, its success. And I think it may be a problem with the request header, so I added same headers of PostMan:

> Authorization: Bearer xxx
>
> Cookie:
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Keep-Alive: timeout=60
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.2
>
> Accept: "*/*"
>
> Postman-Token: cee7d0a1-12ad-4cde-8470-1851b6277d7c
>
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

But the request still timed out.
I want to find the corresponding log at the gateway layer, but it seems that the request did not reach the backend

​   I hope to succeed when request **front-end URL** using OkHttp . I tried my best, but didn't find out why this error occurred.

​   Thank you for providing useful tips.

**OkHttp request:**

> Front-end request URL
> GET  http://127.0.0.1:8000/dev/wf/node
> [Timeout]

> back-end URL
> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/wf/node
> [Success]

**PostMan request:**

> Front-end request URL
> GET  http://127.0.0.1:8000/dev/wf/node
> [Success]

> back-end URL
> GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/wf/node
> [Success]